# Database 'neo4j' not up to the requested version

Tags: python, neo4j

I am running queries on neo4j db using python and it is failing.

Running queries on neo4j using python code are failing. I am getting this error:

> {code: Neo.TransientError.Transaction.BookmarkTimeout} {message: Database 'neo4j' not up to the requested version: 96025349. Latest database version is 96025343}.

How to resolve this error? I am using neo4j library.

Comment: @snakecharmerb That error is not referring to the neo4j version, but to the "bookmark" version used to ensure cluster nodes are in sync.

Comment: [This article](https://aura.support.neo4j.com/hc/en-us/articles/5937489169043-TransientException-Database-not-up-to-the-requested-version) might be helpful. Have your retried your query to see if it goes away? This could be a transient error.